# jquery to select first field with class with spaces

Tags: jquery

I am pulling my hair out trying to select a field by class in jQuery.

```
<input type="text" id="options_55_text" class="fieldy input-text required-entry  validate-length maximum-length-100 product-custom-option" name="options[55][]" value="Some text here" readonly="readonly">
```

I know that i can select the first one using javascript with `document.querySelector(".fieldy")` . That works beautifully, but how would I do it in jQuery?

Comment: your question is not clear enough, please add a better question. Is it like you have 3 same elements next to each other with the same class and you try to select the first one? If so `$(".className).first()`

Comment: Oops, I didn't realise the code I put in got filtered out of the post.  Will try to edit. Edit: Looks like Ashish did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".yourClassName")[0]
```

Is that what you mean? This will give you the first item in the collection of elements with that class name

Comment: OP wants the first field

Comment: Thanks! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices:

1. `$()` to select the set and then [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) (or `eq(0)`) to just target the first: `$(".fieldy").first()`
2. Using jQuery's [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) or [`:eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) pseudo-selector: `$(".fieldy:first")` or `$(".fieldy:eq(0)")`

In both cases, you get a jQuery set with just that first element in it, on which you can use all the usual jQuery methods.

If you want the actual DOM element, jQuery sets are array-like, so you'd use `[0]` on the result of either of the above to access the DOM element itself.

Example:

```js
// Get the jQuery set with just the one element
var fieldy = $(".fieldy:first");

// Use a jQuery method to make the text green
fieldy.css("color", "green");

// Go directly to the DOM element to add a border
fieldy[0].style.border = "1px solid green";
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Not fieldy</div>
  <div class="fieldy">First fieldy</div>
  <div>Not fieldy</div>
  <div class="fieldy">Second fieldy</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: also `nth-child(1)`

Comment: @guradio: No, that will fail for (say) `<div><div>/<div><div class="fieldy">...</div></div>` because the `.fieldy` isn't the first child in its parent. That's why jQuery adds `:first`.